# Updating Graphics on Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, graphics

I'm using GlowScript to display interactive 3D graphics on a website.

I imagine I would mainly be using HTML and JavaScript for this.

I would like to have a button to have a user step between graphics. The graphics in each step would be similar with slight modifications.

I would want to have common code for all graphics and additional code for each of them. But besides that I'm not sure how the code should be structured.

I realize this questions is a bit vague, but I'm mainly just looking for guidance on the general approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly suggest to use framework like bootstrap and you can find sample code in https://codepen.io/

Comment: I had not heard of Bootstrap before and I agree it could be useful to me. However, I'm not sure how to find what I'm looking for using it; does it have anything similar to what I'm trying to do?